# OpenCV: How to detect new object on photo (which was not on previous photos)?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

We have a camera that takes a photos. For i.e. one photo at minute. It can take photos at day and at night, at morning and at evening. So, light and shadows are changing on each photo.

I need to detect does this photo contains a new object (for i.e. man or car on road), which was not there when we set up camera.

Is it possible to do with opencv?

Comment: Look for background subtraction

Comment: OpenCV has a function called MOG2 that should be able to do this for you. Here is a link for reference: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

Comment: you need to establish some "invariance" in the picture, to those things that vary but you don't care about (lighting). -- sample pictures are always a good idea, if you want people to work for you.